# mobile screen showing large gaps inbetween menu items

Tags: html, css, mobile, menu

My mobile menu has large gaps in between the list items, my code does not help me, can anyone else see something?

This is most likely due to `px` or some other screen-scaled metric not translating properly onto the mobile resolution.

I have tried unsuccessfully to upload a supporting image.

```css
html, body 
{
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: auto; margin: 0;
 }

 .nav {
  background-color: #3333FF;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 40px; 
  line-height: 40px;
}

.menu {
  font-family: Monserrat, sans-serif; 
  font-size: 18px; 
  color: white; 
  list-style-type: none; 
  padding: 0; 
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu a {
  text-decoration: none; 
  color: #fff; 
  line-height: 40px; /* Line height 40px, not 40-px */
}

.menu ul li {
  text-align: center; 
  display: inline; 
  padding: 10px; 
  width: 11.11%;
}

.menu li:visited, .menu li:active, .active, .menu li:hover 
{
  background: #0000EE; 
  color: #fff;
}

label {
  margin: 0 14px 0 0; 
  font-size: 20px; 
  display: none;
}

#toggle {
  display: none;
}

/* Show Hamburger */
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  label {
    cursor: pointer; 
    display: block; 
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  .menu {
    text-align: center; 
    width: 100%; 
    display: none;
  }
  
  .menu a {
    display: block; 
    background-color: #999; 
    margin:0; 
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  #toggle:checked + .menu {
    display: block;
  }
} /* A finishing bracket was missing */
```

Comment: I have a picture too, but it will not work here

Comment: Please provide the HTML

Comment: It would be good for you to include your html code as well to let people understand further on your problem.

Comment: You have a line-height: 40px, maybe reduce that and see

Comment: I reduced and removed the line height and it helped but not properly. Thanks for the bracket mention I always forget that.

Comment: Here is some html

Comment: <div class="nav">
<label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle"/>
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li class="current"><a 
    href="http://index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href=" http://news.html">News</a></li>
 <li><a href="http://contacts.html">Contacts</a> 
 </li>
<li><a href="http://policies.html">Policies</a> 
</li>
<li><a href="http://members.html">Members</a></li>
<li><a href="http://volunteer.html">Volunteer</a></li>
<li><a href="http://links.html">Links</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div></div>